# Different stacks found in dump file using Windbg

Tags: windows, windbg, dump

I am using windbg to analyze the dump file of my program.

I can get the stack of the current thread by the following command.

> > kv

Then I run the following command to analyze the dump file.

> > !analyze -v

There is STACK_TEXT in the report of the analysis.

But the question is that **the stack in STACK_TEXT is different from any one that I got from command *~kv.**

> > *~kv

I searched all the threads, found no such stack(the stack in STACK_TEXT).

So Why? Which stack is wrong?

---

Following is the details.

```
STACK_TEXT:  
0b84f930 7415d3df 0b84f954 7417b590 00000000 framework!_woutput_p_l+0xfd8 
0b84f974 7415d460 7416505b 043838c0 00002000 framework!_vswprintf_helper+0x94 
0b84f994 74100ac8 043838c0 00002000 7417b590 framework!_vswprintf_p+0x1d 
0b84f9ac 74100a61 043838c0 00002000 7417b590 framework!CORE::_vprintf+0x18 
0b84f9dc 74106a71 0b84fa50 7417b590 0b84fab0 framework!CORE::corestring<wchar_t>::vprintf+0x61 
0b84fa7c 740f86d4 00000001 7419de40 7417b590 framework!CORE::__SysMessage+0x191 
0b84faa0 740f9203 00000001 7417b590 ffffffff framework!CORE::sysmsg+0x24 
0b84fad4 740f2b48 0000003f 00000000 34c0ee06 framework!remote_framework::ChannelState+0xe3 
0b84fb0c 740f2e92 34c0ee72 7415da34 0435a2c8 framework!channel::closeChannel+0xc8 
0b84fb78 740f1d77 00000000 34c0eeb2 74179b6c framework!channel::recvData+0x162 
0b84fbb8 740f4b36 007fa088 04365e90 0b84fc60 framework!ChannelThread+0x3d7 
0b84fbc8 74104df3 34c0e96a 7415da34 0435a2c8 framework!CORE::corerun::ThreadEntry+0x16
0b84fc60 740f452a 04365e90 34c0e9e2 00000000 framework!CORE::threadwrapper::threadWrapper+0x73 
0b84fce8 7415da0e 04365e90 34c0e82a 7415da34 framework!CORE::corerunnable::runThread+0x27a 
0b84fd20 7415dab6 7415da34 0b84fd40 75037c04 framework!_callthreadstartex+0x1b 
0b84fd2c 75037c04 0435a2c8 75037be0 35cf1bd8 framework!_threadstartex+0x82
0b84fd40 7787ad2f 0435a2c8 374ca77e 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
0b84fd88 7787acfa ffffffff 778600a5 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
0b84fd98 00000000 7415da34 0435a2c8 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
---------
0:086> ~*kv1
   0  Id: 21260.21264 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7f07f000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
003df6e0 753d284f 00000002 003df8a8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
   1  Id: 21260.2126c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7f079000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
011bf73c 7541ddaf 000001ac 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
   2  Id: 21260.21270 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef4f000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0379f5c4 753d284f 00000002 0379f78c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
   3  Id: 21260.21274 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef4c000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0389fa18 753c2cc7 00000228 00000000 0389fa60 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
   4  Id: 21260.21278 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef49000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0454fbec 753c2cc7 000012ac 00000000 0454fc34 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
   5  Id: 21260.2127c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef46000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0464fd2c 753c2cc7 000012b4 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
   6  Id: 21260.21280 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef43000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0478fa88 753c2cc7 000012d8 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
   7  Id: 21260.21288 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef40000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
049ff9fc 753d284f 00000005 043642b4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
   8  Id: 21260.2128c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef3d000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
04b3f78c 753c2cc7 000013c4 00000000 04b3f7d4 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
   9  Id: 21260.21290 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef3a000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
04c7f588 753d284f 00000003 04c7f74c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  10  Id: 21260.21294 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef37000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
04dbf680 753d284f 00000002 04dbf85c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  11  Id: 21260.21298 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef34000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
04eff9b4 753d284f 00000007 04effb7c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  12  Id: 21260.212b0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef31000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0503fc98 753c2cc7 000012ac 00000000 0503fce0 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  13  Id: 21260.212b8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef2b000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0541f9ac 753c2cc7 000014a0 00000000 0541f9f4 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  14  Id: 21260.212c0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef25000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0569f548 753c2cc7 000014b8 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  15  Id: 21260.212c4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef22000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
057df888 753c2cc7 000014c0 00000000 057df8d0 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  16  Id: 21260.212c8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef1f000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0592f500 753d284f 00000002 0592f6c8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  17  Id: 21260.212cc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef1c000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
05a6f7a4 753d284f 00000002 05a6f96c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  18  Id: 21260.212d0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef19000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
05baf8ec 753c2cc7 00001540 00000000 05baf934 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  19  Id: 21260.212d4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef16000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
05cefbec 753d284f 00000002 05cefdb4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  20  Id: 21260.212dc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef13000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
05e2f7e4 753d284f 00000002 05e2f9ac 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  21  Id: 21260.212e0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef10000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
05f7f61c 753d284f 00000002 05f7f7e4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  22  Id: 21260.212e4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef0d000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
060bf75c 753c2cc7 0000157c 00000000 060bf7a4 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  23  Id: 21260.212e8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef0a000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
061ff7cc 753d284f 00000002 061ff994 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  24  Id: 21260.212ec Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef07000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0633f4b4 753d284f 00000002 0633f67c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  25  Id: 21260.212f0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef04000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0647fc1c 753d284f 00000002 0647fde4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  26  Id: 21260.212f4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef01000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
065bf67c 753d284f 00000002 065bf844 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  27  Id: 21260.212f8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eefe000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
066ff438 753d284f 00000002 066ff600 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  28  Id: 21260.212fc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eefb000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0683fa84 753d284f 00000002 0683fc4c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  29  Id: 21260.21300 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eef8000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0697f9ac 753d284f 00000002 0697fb74 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  30  Id: 21260.21304 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eef5000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
06bbf59c 753d284f 00000002 06bbf764 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  31  Id: 21260.21308 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eef2000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
06cff5dc 753d284f 00000002 06cff7a4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  32  Id: 21260.2130c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeef000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
06e3f6d8 753d284f 00000002 06e3f8a0 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  33  Id: 21260.21310 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeec000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
06f7fca4 753c2cc7 000015dc 00000000 06f7fcec ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  34  Id: 21260.21314 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eee9000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
070bfc90 753c2cc7 000015e4 00000000 070bfcd8 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  35  Id: 21260.21318 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eee6000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
071ffb00 753d284f 00000002 071ffcc8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  36  Id: 21260.2131c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eee3000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0733f624 753c2cc7 000008dc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  37  Id: 21260.21320 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eee0000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0747fc00 753d284f 00000002 0747fdc8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  38  Id: 21260.21324 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eedd000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
075bf420 753d284f 00000002 075bf5e8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  39  Id: 21260.21328 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeda000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
076ff898 753d284f 00000002 076ffa60 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  40  Id: 21260.2132c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eed7000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0783fa6c 753d284f 00000002 0783fc34 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  41  Id: 21260.21330 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eed4000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0797f6a8 753d284f 00000002 0797f870 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  42  Id: 21260.21334 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eed1000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
07abf5a0 753d284f 00000002 07abf768 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  43  Id: 21260.21338 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eece000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
07bffaac 753d284f 00000002 07bffc74 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  44  Id: 21260.2133c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eecb000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
07d3f55c 753d284f 00000002 07d3f724 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  45  Id: 21260.21340 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eec8000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
07e7f754 753d284f 00000002 07e7f91c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  46  Id: 21260.21344 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eec5000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
07fbf50c 753d284f 00000002 07fbf6d4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  47  Id: 21260.21348 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eec2000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
080ff814 753d284f 00000002 080ff9dc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  48  Id: 21260.2134c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eebf000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0823f718 753d284f 0000000d 050845cc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  49  Id: 21260.21350 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eebc000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0837fb4c 753d284f 00000002 0837fd14 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  50  Id: 21260.21354 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeb9000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
084bfa28 753c2cc7 00001668 00000000 084bfa70 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  51  Id: 21260.21358 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeb6000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
085ff7c4 753d284f 00000002 085ff98c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  52  Id: 21260.2135c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeb3000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0873fab8 753d284f 00000002 0873fc80 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  53  Id: 21260.21360 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeb0000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0887f884 753d284f 00000002 0887fa4c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  54  Id: 21260.21364 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eead000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
089bf8b0 753d284f 00000002 089bfa78 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  55  Id: 21260.21368 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eeaa000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
08aff5f0 753d284f 00000002 08aff7b8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  56  Id: 21260.2136c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eea7000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
08c3f9f0 753d284f 00000002 08c3fbb8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  57  Id: 21260.21370 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eea4000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
08d7fb0c 753d284f 00000002 08d7fcd4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  58  Id: 21260.21374 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7eea1000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
08ebf6a0 753d284f 00000002 08ebf868 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  59  Id: 21260.21378 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee9e000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
08fff854 753d284f 00000002 08fffa1c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  60  Id: 21260.2137c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee9b000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0913f934 753d284f 00000002 0913fafc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  61  Id: 21260.21380 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee98000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0937f754 753d284f 00000002 0937f91c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  62  Id: 21260.21384 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee95000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
094bf568 753d284f 00000002 094bf730 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  63  Id: 21260.21388 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee92000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
095ff994 753d284f 00000002 095ffb5c 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  64  Id: 21260.2138c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee8f000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0973fa14 753d284f 00000002 0973fbdc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  65  Id: 21260.21390 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee8c000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0987f8f4 753d284f 00000002 0987fabc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  66  Id: 21260.21394 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee89000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
099bf52c 753d284f 00000002 099bf6f4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  67  Id: 21260.21398 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee86000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
09affbb0 753d284f 00000002 09affd78 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  68  Id: 21260.2139c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee83000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
09c3f4a0 753d284f 00000002 09c3f668 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  69  Id: 21260.213a0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee80000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
09d7fa00 753d284f 00000002 09d7fbc8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  70  Id: 21260.213a4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee7d000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
09ebf520 753d284f 00000002 09ebf6e8 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  71  Id: 21260.213a8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee7a000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
09fff50c 753d284f 00000002 09fff6d4 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  72  Id: 21260.213ac Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee77000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0a13f4a4 7547b8c8 0000172c 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwFsControlFile+0xc (FPO: [10,0,0])
  73  Id: 21260.213b4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee71000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0a3bfc70 753d284f 00000002 0a3bfe24 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  74  Id: 21260.213b8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee6e000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0a4ffbb0 753d284f 00000002 0a4ffd64 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  75  Id: 21260.213bc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee6b000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0a63f200 753d284f 00000002 0a63f828 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  76  Id: 21260.213c0 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee68000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0a7af4b4 7750f10e 000a004a 0000031a 011e000b user32!NtUserMessageCall+0xc (FPO: [7,0,0])
  77  Id: 21260.213c4 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee65000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0aa0f80c 753d284f 00000002 0aa0f9c0 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  78  Id: 21260.213c8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee62000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0ab4fb80 753d284f 00000002 0ab4fd34 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  79  Id: 21260.213cc Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee5f000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0ac8f50c 753d284f 00000002 0ac8f6c0 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  80  Id: 21260.21044 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee59000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0af4f8ac 753c2cc7 000014a0 00000000 0af4f8f4 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  81  Id: 21260.1e998 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee56000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0b0afa0c 753c2cc7 000014ac 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  82  Id: 21260.2103c Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee53000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0b1efa84 753d284f 00000006 050795dc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
  83  Id: 21260.5f68 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee50000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0b33f930 753c2cc7 000014c0 00000000 0b33f978 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  84  Id: 21260.79f8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee4d000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0b47f790 753c2cc7 000014c0 00000000 0b47f7d8 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
  85  Id: 21260.21058 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee4a000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0b5bfd2c 7783ffd3 00001904 005ea308 00000010 ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
\# 86  Id: 21260.cb04 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ee44000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0b84d504 77869393 00000001 0b84d6b4 778b7480 ntdll!ZwGetContextThread+0xc (FPO: [2,0,0])
  87  Id: 21260.1a090 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ef2e000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
052dfc20 7783ffd3 0000005c 005e1760 00000010 ntdll!ZwWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
```

Sorry for the long infolist. It is a huge process so there are a lot of threads in it.

Comment: Can you post the output of `!analyze -v` and the `*~kv1 commands?

Comment: @MichaelBurr  Thanks Michael. I attached the details.

Comment: Is there an exception? I assume that the context is not set correctly. Try `.ecxr -1` and then `*~kv`

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks Tomas. If I input .ecxr before kv, the output stack will be the one in STACK_TEXT.  And there is a line "Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it". But *~kv still don't have this one.

Comment: I'm not sure why it does that but `~*e .ecxr;kv` might be a workaround